# Summing an infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, factorial

I have been struggling with a problem involving a Markov Chain.  To solve it I need to figure out the following sum:$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{[\lambda(k-1)+\theta][\lambda(k-2)+\theta][\lambda(k-3)+\theta]\cdots[\lambda+\theta]\theta}{(k!)^2\mu^k}$$

Where, $\lambda=0.3$, $\theta=0.1$, $\mu=0.03$.

Cheers.

Comment: $n$ does not appear anywhere except in the denominator. Is it normal ?

Comment: Hey Claude, Sorry about that.  Just fixed it up.

Comment: what happen between these two terms $[\lambda(k-3)+\theta]\cdots[\lambda+\theta]$??? I dont see a clear relation going from $(k-3)$ to $1$.

Comment: Coefficient of lambda decreases by 1 in each set of brackets.

Comment: Yes but how you go from a expression where k decreases by one to one expression where isnt k anymore. This means that the length of numerator is defined to the maximum when $k-x=1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering $$S=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{[\lambda(k-1)+\theta][\lambda(k-2)+\theta][\lambda(k-3)+\theta]...[\lambda+\theta]\theta}{(k!)^2\mu^k}$$ and using a CAS, the numerator in the summation is $$\theta\prod_{i=1}^{k-1} (\lambda i +\theta)=\theta  \lambda ^{k-1} \left(\frac{\theta +\lambda }{\lambda }\right)_{k-1}$$ where appears  the Pochhammer symbol.

So, the result is $$S=\, _1F_1\left(\frac{\theta }{\lambda };1;\frac{\lambda }{\mu }\right)-1$$ where appears the Kummer confluent hypergeometric function. It can also write $$S=L_{-\frac{\theta }{\lambda }}\left(\frac{\lambda }{\mu }\right)-1$$  where appears  the Laguerre polynomial.

Using the numbers $\lambda=0.3$, $\theta=0.1$, $\mu=0.03$, we then obtain $$S=1864.59998928641$$

I hope this helps.

Comment: You are very welcome !